# PHP - Open or copy a file when knowing only part of its name?

Tags: php, file, search

I have a huge repository of files that are ordered by numbered folders. In each folder is a file which starts with a unique number then an unknown string of characters. Given the unique number how can i open or copy this file?

for example:
I have been given the number '7656875' and nothing more.
I need to interact with a file called '\server\7656800\7656875 foobar 2x4'.

how can i achieve this using PHP?

Comment: why the weird naming conventions?

Comment: just the way a company names files..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the directory name, consider using [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

```
$matches = glob('./server/dir/'.$num.'*');
```

Then if there is only one file that should start with the number, take the first (and only) match.

Answer (score 3):

Like [Yacoby suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692012/php-open-or-copy-a-file-when-knowing-only-part-of-its-name/2692040#2692040), `glob` should do the trick. You can have multiple placeholders in it as well, so if you know the depth, but not the correct naming, you can do:

```
$matchingFiles = glob('/server/*/7656875*');
```

which would match

```
"/server/12345/7656875 foo.txt"
"/server/56789/7656875 bar.jpg"
```

but not

```
"/server/12345/subdir/7656875 foo.txt"
```

If you do not know the depth `glob()` won't help, you can use a [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) passing in the top most folder path, e.g.

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/server'));

foreach($iterator as $fileObject) {
    // assuming the filename begins with the number
    if(strpos($fileObject->getFilename(), '7656875') === 0) {
         // do something with the $fileObject, e.g.
         copy($fileObject->getPathname(), '/somewhere/else');
         echo $fileObject->openFile()->fpassthru();
    }
}
```

<sub>* Note: code is untested but should work</sub>

[DirectoryIterator](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) return [SplFileInfo](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) objects, so you can use them to directly access the files through a high-level API.

Comment: I don't have the karma to edit your answer so will note that the above code (at the time of writing this) will not work as expected due to a typo on the `strpos` line. Feel free to remove this comment if/when the typo is no longer there. :-)

Comment: @salathe thanks. corrected. Comments can only be removed by moderators.

Comment: Gordon, no worries. Other useful Iterators for this question would be: [`GlobIterator`](http://php.net/globiterator), to get the best of both worlds; or the [[`Recursive`](http://php.net/recursiveregexiterator)] [`RegexIterator`](http://php.net/regexiterator), to be even more specific about which files to glob.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = system("ls \server\" . $specialNumber . '\');
$fh = fopen($result, 'r');
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's hidden below in sub-sub-directories of variable length, use `find`

```
echo `find . -name "*$input*"`;
```

Explode and trim each result, then hope you found the correct one.